# Virtual PC on Windows 7 doesn't have adjustment for video card size?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

The current VirtualBox has a place where the video card RAM size can be set by the user.

It seems that Win 7's Virtual PC doesn't have one?

Will it auto adjust -- but what if the screen size is 800 x 600 and the user resize it to 1600 x 1200, then the original video size may not be enough and will that cause any problem?

I do sometimes see blinking random pixel region showing on the VPC's screen... maybe it is cause by not enough video RAM size?

Comment: oh is it because you won't get the 15 points of an accepted answer?  sometimes I feel that some answers are somewhat open, and if 1 answer received 3 votes and the other 2 answers received 1 vote, then it is very apparent which is a good answer.  Sometimes, all answers received 1 vote and there really is not definite standard answer and that's why i won't particularly accept one.  but this create repercussion in this website.

Comment: You shouldn't be be asking open-ended questions.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2005/11/21/494961.aspx

> **Virtual PC and video ram**
>
> Virtual PC emulates an S3 Trio 64 Video card with 8mb of video ram (VRAM).  From time to time I get people asking me why we do not increase the amount of VRAM - and there are a couple of reasons why:
>
> VRAM is a fixed overhead.  Each virtual machine that you launch uses 8mb of your computers memory to store our VRAM information.  If we increase this - it will increase the amount of memory used for each virtual machine - whether the virtual machine is using this extra memory or not.
>
> On video cards with hardware 3D acceleration support VRAM is used for storage of textures, and other performance improving measures.  However with a 2D video card VRAM is only used to store a single frame buffer of the contents on screen.  This means that with a 2D video card (such as we emulate) adding more VRAM just allows you to support higher resolutions - but it does not provide better performance.  **At 8mb we are able to display at up to 1600x1200 resolutions.**

So basically the user can set up to 1600x1200, the VRAM size does not need to be adjusted.

You can edit the VMC file to have up to 16mb of VRAM, however.

```
<video_adapter> 
    <vram_size type="integer">16</vram_size> 
</video_adapter>
```

Comment: ah, i have a 1920 x 1200 display, so sometimes i may "accidentally resize it" to be 1920 x 1000.

Comment: if we can resize it to 16MB, can it be 32MB too? or the video card's limit is 16MB?

Comment: also, the article was close to 5 years ago... with Win 7's virtual PC, maybe it could step up to a more current usage.

Comment: by the way, with Win 7's VPC, if I right click on desktop's empty space, and look at the screen resolution, and then click "Advanced", and then Adapter, then I see that it is 16MB without changing any setting.

Comment: Presumably Windows 7's Virtual PC beefs up the default adapter to 16MB.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: Good info Ben!.. IS there anyway to support VESA for a DOS 6.22 on VPC2007?.. I need to display 132 columns wide screens.